# log4j: fastest way to display method name?

Tags: performance, methods, log4j

In my logging messages, I need to insert the name of the method where the messages were produced. I've looked at Log4J documentation and "M" and "l" conversion chars that also have warning like "WARNING Generating caller location information is extremely slow and should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue". So I have (at least) two options:

1. Use these chars but slow down my code
2. Manually insert method name into messages, i.e. something like this `log.info("myMethod:  message");` which will be faster but not as elegant

Are there any other options that would not slow down my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure of the IDE that you are using, but if you are using Eclipse based IDE's you should be able to use some Java templates. This will still be using the method names as strings,but will save you typing time.

I created a whole set of templates like this:

- Template name - `li`
- Pattern - `logger.info("${cursor}");`

and so on for `warn`, `error`, and `debug`.

For start and end of method, or just to add method name to every log out - use something like:

- Template name - `lie`
- Pattern - `logger.info("End: ${enclosing_method}${cursor}");`

and so on.

The only constraint is your logger ref variable will always have to be named `logger`.
Now you will just need to type `lie` and (optionally hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> if you uncheck the *Automatically Insert* checkbox at template creation time.)

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

I use the basic configurator most of the times and it gives me the method name by default. So technically adding just this single line of code and the import statement is the fastest way to get what you are asking for.

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

Answer (score 0):

If there were a non-slow way of programmatically retrieving this information, log4j would use it- unfortunately there isn't, because it's not information that the JVM has been designed to make easily available to the runtime environment.

This is why most logging code only uses patterns which retrieve this information at the debug level- and then wraps all debug calls in a `if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {` condition, so that the information is only retrieved when the program is in debug mode. This approach enables you to get fine-grained runtime information when you are debugging, without impacting the performance of your code when it is in production.

It's also important to remember that not all code is performance-intensive, and if your code runs and scales fine with these patterns in use, then you might as well just use them. If you start having performance issues, then you can reconsider.

As an aside, the Groovy language (since version 1.8) has AST transforms which inject loggers (of the java.util, apache commons, log4j or slf4j flavours) into your classes automatically- and will also automatically wrap all logging calls in conditions at compile time so that they are only run when logging is at the appropriate level. This means that you can do what I described above without having to explicitly code the conditionals, but of course is only available if you're writing Groovy.

Comment: slf4j handles only logging message of the appropriate level, I believe. It also supports "scanf" syntax so that string concat operations can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a more current solution if you use log4j with slf4j, I wrote a **maven-plugin** addressing this issue, while not generating any performance issues either:
https://github.com/PhilKes/slf4j-caller-info-maven-plugin

This plugin **injects the class name, optionally also the method name and source code line number into SLF4J log statements at compile time** (see [configuration](https://github.com/PhilKes/slf4j-caller-info-maven-plugin#configuration)).
All you need to do is to add the `callerInformation` MDC parameter to your log-pattern (see [Code Example](https://github.com/PhilKes/slf4j-caller-info-maven-plugin#code-example)) and add the plugin in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
 <groupId>io.github.philkes</groupId>
 <artifactId>slf4j-caller-info-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.0</version>
 <executions>
   <execution>
     <goals>
        <goal>inject</goal>
     </goals>
   </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```